# Put a TreeViewer in a Table Column

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have two fully operational TreeViewers. I decided I would like to put them in Column 1 and Column 3 of a Table.

Is that possible?

Comment: If you eventually find a solution, please post it here.

Comment: @Baz I ditched this approach and simply found another way to present the information. I would have preferred this way but figuring it out was too time consuming. When I have time though I will see if I can come up with it